# Line Graphs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Some details around what I'm using:

```
    Jupyter Notebook (v. 5.4)
    matplotlib (v. 2.1.2)
    Python (v. 3.6.4)
```

The specific question:  I am trying to create a multi-line graph for PKa Data (y-axis) over the Nominal_Timepoint (x-axis) by unique ID (from ID column).  In a perfect world, there will be two lines on the graph (one for each unique ID in the ID column) and the x-axis would be ordered by Nominal_Timepoint.

Here's what I have so far in terms of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
%matplotlib inline

pkc = pd.read_excel("NAME OF FILE.xlsx", usecols = [1,2,3,4,7,8])
pkc['PKa Data']=pkc['PKa Data'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
pkc['PKb Data']=pkc['PKb Data'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
pkc

ID       Cohort  Day             Nominal_Timepoint   PKa_Data PKb_Data
101002   1       Cycle 1 Day 1   Pre-Dose            NaN      NaN
101002   1       Cycle 1 Day 1   30-Minutes          9.190    NaN
101002   1       Cycle 1 Day 1   1 hr                15.200   NaN
101002   1       Cycle 2 Day 1   Pre-Dose            52.400   0.666
101002   1       Cycle 2 Day 1   30-Minutes          30.200   0.582
101002   1       Cycle 2 Day 1   1 hr                76.900   0.869
202001   2       Cycle 1 Day 1   Pre-Dose            NaN      NaN
202001   2       Cycle 1 Day 1   30-Minutes          0.941    NaN
202001   2       Cycle 1 Day 1   1 hr                8.340    NaN
202001   2       Cycle 2 Day 1   Pre-Dose            112.000  1.750
202001   2       Cycle 2 Day 1   30-Minutes          103.000  1.730
202001   2       Cycle 2 Day 1   1 hr                97.400   1.570

plt.plot(pkc['Nominal_Timepoint'], pkc['PKa_Data'])
```

Currently, the graph looks like this:

[image: Graph with unordered x axis].

You can see in the picture that the x-axis is not ordered right and there should only be two lines on the graph given there are only two unique IDs in the ID column. I've explored a bunch of online matplotlib tutorials and I can't seem to get this to work.  Any other help would be much appreciated.  I had this question earlier, but it was put on hold (though i'm not sure why, but I did modify this question to try and be a bit more clear).  Crediting where credit is due, the plt.plot code above was provided by Goyo and that at least got me the picture attached above.

Comment: Each ID has several occurances of the same Timepoint. So it's not clear how you envision the graph to look like.

Comment: If you update matplotlib to version 2.2, the xlabels will be in the order they occur in the dataframe (and of course you may sort your dataframe prior to plotting to achieve any order you like).

Comment: I appreciate your response, but a graph using this data would look simply like a line graph for ID 101002 at timepoints Pre-Dose, 30-Minutes, and 1-hr.  I believe this is the same person that put my last question on hold?  If you don't understand the question, please let someone else answer

Comment: As said, you have two values of e.g. `Pre-Dose` for the ID `101002`. The graph hence needs to jump back and forth, even if you divide your plotting into one plot per ID. Therefore it is necessary that you tell us what should happen instead. Would you like 4 lines in total rather than 2? (Your last question was so unclear that it was indeed closed, I voted to close *before* you clarified things in a way that would allow to even remotely understand the issue, my comments here are there to help you ask a question which can be answered and is then useful for future readers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort out your time points.  At the moment, you can see what happened: `plot` is *trying* to interpolate data points along your given range of "1 hr", "30-Minutes", and "Pre-Dose", with no reference whatsoever to cycle or day.

Use the timedata type to construct another column that gives a numeric-cognate type that `plot` can use.  Make sure that the first value is for cycle 1, pre-dose; then cycle 1, 30 minutes; and so on.  You need six distinct values *of the same value type* in order.  Use that as your x-axis values.

Your current code implies hours, minutes, and text, so `plot` is having problems reading your mind.

Is that enough of a hint to get you moving?

Comment: Very much appreciated